# Why are some runways apparently wobbly?

Tags: commercial-aviation, runways

In [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7P9OAng32F0), there are several examples at 0:34, 1:15, and 1:27. You can see the runway looks wobbly. That last one appears to have at least three wobbles in it.

These are runways on which large commercial jumbo jets are landing, so presumably they're built to world-class standards. Do these standards allow for such wobbling along they're length? If so how is that possible?

Comment: Note also that those shots are taken with very long telephoto lenses, which make perspective look very compressed. The hills on the runway at 0:34 look very steep but, in reality, they're much shallower.

Comment: There are a lot of tricks of perspective here, the runway looks like its barely 1000 feet long, but in reality 15/33 at BHX is 8527 feet (over a mile and a half). It also looks like a lot of the aircraft either hover, come down fast, or rocket into the air but they are probably pretty close to the 3° glideslope.